# Delete the first 25 lines of a .txt document

Tags: javascript, readfile, delete-file

I want to delete the first 25 lines of text from a .txt bots document every time when I use a command on my discord server (I know how to do that by command but I dont know how to delete the rows)

```
var text = fs.readFileSync("./data/bots.txt", "utf-8");
var bot = text.split("\n")
```

btw I cant skip them every 25 first lines because the bots file is 10.000 lines long and every time a bot is used it should be deleted from the docs

Comment: Can you read line by line, skip the first 25, write the rest to a new file? Then rename to the original name

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that each line is separated by a new line, I would:

1. Read file
2. Form array, split by new line
3. Return lines 25 -> End
4. Change from array back to string
5. Write new file

So I'd do this with nodejs:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const text = fs.readFileSync("./data/bots.txt", "utf8");
const textArr = text.split("\n");
// This removes the 25th line as well, if you want to keep it
// change it to 24
const textArrNew = textArr.slice(25);
const string = textArrNew.join("\n");
fs.writeFileSync("new2.txt", string);
```

Comment: The bot its setted up to read bots.txt file why do you want to create new2.txt or should I import 25 accounts from allbots.txt then create bots.txt file where the process will paste the 25 then after my bot loada them delete bots.txt or delete content

Comment: Using your code I need to tell my bot to import from new2.txt and also delete new2.txt or empty the content because I dont want to be used again the accounts (25)